# Awk remove specific characters

Tags: bash, awk

I have command, which gives me output from telnet. Full output from telnet It looks like this:

```
telnet myserver.com 1234
```

> Server, Name=MyServer, Age=123, Ver=1.23, ..., ..., ...

This command should filter just the number after Age - "Age=**123**" which I want to filter:

```
echo "\n" | nc myserver.com 1234 | (awk -F "=" '{print $3}')
```

Instead of **123** it gives me this output:

> 123, Ver

Is there a way how to get just number after *Age=*?

It's just bad awk filtering parameter, but I tried some other ways with awk but this gave me almost best result... Thank you for any help.

Edit: I forgot, number after Age= is dynamic +1 every day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "\n" | nc myserver.com 1234 | awk -F "," '{print substr($3,6)}'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the `echo "\n"` part but I think that this should do what you want:

```
nc myserver.com 1234 | awk -F "," '{ split($3, a, /=/); print a[2] }'
```

Instead of splitting into fields on the `=`, I've done so on the `,`. The third field is then split into the array `a` on the `=` and the second half is printed.

I also removed the `( )` around the invocation of awk, which was creating a subshell unnecessarily.

If you're confident about the response never varying containing `=` or `,` in other places, you could simplify the awk expression further:

```
awk -F'[=,]' '{ print $5 }'
```

The bracket expression allows fields to be split on either `=` or `,`, making the part you're interested in the fifth field.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the awk command twice.

```
awk -F "=" '{print $3}'|awk -F "," '{print $1}'
```

You can also use the cut command:

```
cut -d "=" -f 3|cut -d "," -f 1
```